# IE11's developer tools are broken

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

Sadly, we still have to support Internet Explorer 11. The development tools on the version installed on my Windows 10 laptop are broken, as shown in the included image. Has anyone seen this before or have any idea how to fix it?

I rebooted yesterday after installing the latest Windows 10 updates. I realise Internet Explorer 11 is practically embedded into Windows 10 and can't be uninstalled or re-installed. I even tried to reset Internet Explorer 11's settings via the control panel, but that had no effect. I uninstalled the community edition of Visual Studio I had installed, based on the linked post I read that said it may be causing issues. But that didn't fix anything.

When I open the developer tools using <kbd>F12</kbd>, the browser freezes for almost 10 seconds before it ends up as shown in the screenshot. So perhaps it's trying to load the developer tools but they're unavailable or broken?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will unpin the tools and make them usable, but that doesn't fix the problem as shown. Here is the screenshot of broken developer tools:

[image: Screenshot of broken developer tools]

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: IE11 is to soon be dead, I doubt Microsoft cares about development tools.

Comment: That's a good point. I wouldn't care but we have to still support IE11 in our organisation and sadly, it'll be a while before that changes. Thanks.

Comment: All I can say is Good Luck my friend.

Comment: I just want to give the dead horse a kick too. IE11 is only required because developers are too lazy, too incompetent or the company is too cheap to fix the problem. There is absolutely zero excuse to be running an application that still “requires” IE11. IE11 was slated to be removed from Windows 10 already but somehow managed to make it in to the current versions. Your problem is not the developer tools, you should be putting 100% effort in to getting rid of this requirement. That’s your real issue. It’s going to be unpleasantly forced on you if that difficult decision can’t be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall and reinstall ie.

1. open control panel 
   2.Programs -> *Programs and Features*
2. Click on *Turn Windows features on or off*
3. Scroll down to *Internet Explorer 11*
4. Uncheck folder
5. click yes to continue
6. restart
7. follow the same instructions again but this time enable/check IE folder
8. Restart
9. Cross your fingers and try developer tools again

Comment: Thanks - i looked at the app list in the new-fangled Settings app but it wasn't listed there. I completely forgot about the old-fangled control panel.

Comment: No problem. Yeah a lot of control panel settings haven't been migrated to the new settings ui.